# Duplicate single row to an exiting dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, copy, row

I want to make a copy of one specific row (S1,V105) in dataframe and add it below the original one in the same but copied dataframe. Dataframe looks like this:

```
df1
    Session Subject 
    S1      V105   
    S2      V105
```

Result would look like this:

```
df2 = df1.copy()
    df2
        Session Subject 
        S1      V105    
        S1      V105    
        S2      V105
```

What would be

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the row, add 0.5 to the copy's index, then append the copy to the dataframe, sort and reset the indices, like so:

```
row_copy = df2.iloc[[row_index]]
row_copy.rename(index={row_index: row_index + 0.5}, inplace=True)
df2 = df2.append(row_copy, ignore_index=False)
df2.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Alternatively, you can split your dataframe in two and use concat to insert the duplicate row:

```
line = df2.iloc[[row_index]]
df2 = concat([df.iloc[:row_index], line, df.iloc[row_index:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```